# fetch all account/service account having access to particular bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-storage

we are working on one requirement where we want to check that which service account having what type of access on particular GCS bucket from cloud composer.
For dataset we can use below code,

```
dataset = client.get_dataset(dataset_id)  # Make an API request.
entries = list(dataset.access_entries)
```

we are looking some thing similar to this for gcs bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Policy Analyser service](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-iam-policies-samples) that you can find in the Asset Inventory section (sure, it's not obvious)

You can try that query for instance

```
gcloud asset search-all-iam-policies --scope=projects/<ProjectID> --asset-types="storage.googleapis.com/Bucket"
```

And then filter only on the bucket that you target (use `jq` for instance). You can also search at the folder or organization scope to get also the inherited roles from  higher levels.

Comment: Thanks blaquiere i will check this way